# How Chaincode features works in Hyperledger 2.x version?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

How Chaincode features works? How following chaincode features are achieved

1. Chaincode lifecycle flow is used in 2.x where all the organization have their say in chaincode to be used in channel in which chaincode definition is committed to ledger. At what point this committed chaincode definition is used? Is this chaincode definition committed to channel later used by peer and orderer when ordering the transaction to check if there are correct endorsements?
2. Lifecycle 2.x allows to add different chaincode logic on the peers and checkcommit readiness still returns true when organization even approves different chaincode packages.

How this works?
Why different fingerprint is not detected as was detected in v1.4?
At what point this fingerprint check is done

Answer (score 0):

> Chaincode lifecycle flow is used in 2.x where all the organization
> have their say in chaincode to be used in channel in which chaincode
> definition is committed to ledger. At what point this committed
> chaincode definition is used? Is this chaincode definition committed
> to channel later used by peer and orderer when ordering the
> transaction to check if there are correct endorsements?

The 1.x lifecycle has a definition in the "lscc" namespace.
Similarly, the 2.x lifecycle has a definition in the "_lifecycle" namespace.
The chaincode definition is used at the validation of the transaction.
The lifecycle namespace (lscc or _lifecycle namespace) can be thought of as a table that has a row for each application chaincode, and the primary key of the table is the application chaincode name.

> Lifecycle 2.x allows to add different chaincode logic on the peers and
> checkcommit readiness still returns true when organization even
> approves different chaincode packages.

Right, what is important for the 2.x lifecycle is the endorsement policy of the chaincode, and the code itself is not important because the code content does not end up being part of the lifecycle namespace.
This is to make the smart contracts more flexible and to support different logic for different organizations, or have organizations be able to update the dependencies of their chaincodes without needing to collaborate with other organizations on a chaincode upgrade.

> How this works? Why different fingerprint is not detected as was
> detected in v1.4? At what point this fingerprint check is done

In 1.x, the code package of the chaincode was part of the fingerprint. Now, in 2.x it's not part of the fingerprint anymore and you only care about the "chaincode sequence".

For more info check the [lifecycle playback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvEMDScFU2M), Jason mentions fingerprinting at time ~ 30m in the video and about sequences at ~ 25m.